# why sizeof(Base) is not different of sizeof(Derived)

Tags: c++, sizeof, virtual-functions, memory-layout, vptr

I think `sizeof(Base)` should be 12. Why is it 16?

Without the virtual function, I get 4 and 8.

```cpp
class Base{
  public:
    int i;
    virtual void Print(){cout<<"Base Print";}
};

class Derived:public Base{
  public:
    int n;
    virtual void Print(){cout<<"Derived Print";}
};

int main(){
  Derived d;
  cout<<sizeof(Base)<<","<<sizeof(d);
  return 0;
}
```

expected result：12，16

actual result：16，16

Comment: Maybe a padding issue?

Answer (score 8):

> why sizeof(Base) is not different of sizeof(Derived)

Because of the *alignment* introduced by the compiler.

That is *architecture-dependent*, but for sake of simplicity, I am going to assume we are referring a 64-bit architecture.

[Scenario 64 bit / Clang 8.0](https://godbolt.org/z/q4OxGG).

The alignment of the type `Base` is `8` bytes:

```
alignOfBase(): # @alignOfBase()
  mov eax, 8
  ret
```

The layout of `Base` is composed by the variable member (`int`) and the virtual table (`vtptr`).

If we assume a "common" architecture where:

- `int` is 4 bytes size.
- `vtptr` is a pointer. On a 64 bit architecture is 8 bytes size.

We should have a sum of `4 + 8 = 12`, as you expect.

However, we need to remember the alignment of `Base` is `8 bytes`. Therefore consecutive `Base` types should be stored in location multiple of 8.

In order to guarantee that, the compiler introduces padding for `Base`. That's why `Base` is 16 bytes size.

For example, if we consider 2 consecutive `Base` (`base0` and `base1`) without padding:

```
0:  vtptr (base 0) + 8
8:  int   (base 0) + 4
12: vtptr (base 1) + 8  <--- Wrong! The address 12 is not multiple of 8.
20: int   (base 1) + 4
```

With padding:

```
0:  vtptr (base 0) + 8
8:  int   (base 0) + 4+4   (4 padding)
16: vtptr (base 1) +8      <--- Fine! The adress 16 is multiple of 8.
24: int   (base 1) +4+4    (4 padding)
```

---

The same story is for `Derived` type.

The layout of `Derived` should be: `vtptr + int + int`, that is, `8 + 4 + 4 = 16`.

The alignment of `Derived` is `8` too:

```
alignOfDerived(): # @alignOfDerived()
  mov eax, 8
  ret
```

Indeed, in this case, there is no need to introduce padding in order to keep the `Derived` aligned with the memory. The layout size will be the same as the real size.

```
0:   vtptr (Derived 0)
8:   int   (Derived 0)
12:  int   (Derived 0)
16:  vtptr (Derived 1)  <---- Fine. 16 is multiple of 8.
24:  int   (Derived 1)
28:  int   (Derived 1)
```

Comment: You forgot to explain the difference between arrays and structs: `struct { T x1, x2; };` (in principle) could have padding, but `T x[2]` by definition can't, so anything that can be in an array (any concrete object type) must have a size compatible with its alignment.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to compiler deciding to align your classes.

If you want (or need) structs or classes to have their "real" sizes, you can use `#pragma pack(1)` like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // Set packing to 1 byte and push old packing value to stack

class Base{
  public:
    int i;
    virtual void Print(){cout<<"Base Print";}
};

class Derived:public Base{
  public:
    int n;
    virtual void Print(){cout<<"Derived Print";}
};

int main(){
  Derived d;
  cout<<sizeof(Base)<<","<<sizeof(d);
  return 0;
}

#pragma pack(pop) // restore old packing value
```

Comment: Note that unless you have a very strong reason for bypassing the alignment rules you probably shouldn't do it.

Comment: Thank you, it really help me.

Comment: N.B. `#pragma pack` is a compiler extension.